# Make nav bar various level of transparency RGBA

Tags: css, navigation, rgba

I am trying to make a navagation bar with .7 opacity, but the very end needs to be basically completely transparent, so my logo title can show through more. Originally, I was using opacity, but realized that was not the way to go as the child's opacity could not be changed and it would adopt the parent, so then I studied up on RGBA, but apparently, I am doing it wrong because it is not working.

CSS Code

```
#nav {
    width: 100%; /* Spans the width of the page */
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 0; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
    z-index: 99; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: rgb(94, 185, 176); /* The Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(94, 185, 176, .7); /* Make nav bar transparent to a degree */
    margin-top:-45px; /* Make the nav bar overlap the header */
}

.navbar {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute; /* Ensures that the menu doesn't affect other elements */
    border-right: 1px solid #54879d; 
    margin-top:0px;
}

/* First Navigation List different than rest */

#nav.navbar li.first {
    height: 50px;
    width: 133px;
    background-color: rgb(94, 185, 176); /* The Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(94, 185, 176, 0); /* Make first section completly   transparent*/
}

.navbar li.first:hover, a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/*All other Navigation Lists */

.navbar li  {
    height: 50px;
    width: 145px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(94, 185, 176); /* The Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(94, 185, 176, .7); /* Make nav bar transparent to a    degree */
    font-family: 'raindrops';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

(and the code continues on for other things)

I want the whole nav bar 0.7 opacity, but just the far left one to be completely transparent.

Here is the HMTL for that section

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul class="navbar">
 <li class="first"></li>
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

So I need the li class="first" to be completely transparent, and then all the rest with the nav links to be 0.7 transparency, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you have said "Making the first li completely transparent"

```
#nav li:first-child{
     background-color: rgba(94, 185, 176, 0);
}
```

This is what you have to do, but because of the fallback background color you have given. even it's fully transparent you aren't seeing because of the fallback.

Edit : as you have background color in **#nav** now for all li the background color is background color of **#nav** so, making first div completely transparent is having background color of **#nav**

**How about via gradient : **

```
#nav {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, rgba(200, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(94, 185, 176, 0.7) 50%);
}
```

Comment: I just tried that.  It made my drop down list first element transparent, rather than the far left side of the nav bar.  My wesbite [link](www.tutorwithkatie.org).  Somehow, it isn't even making the whole navbar 70% opacity anymore.  Only the far left and far right side have 70% opacity.  I want the far left to be completely transparent, and the rest of the nav bar at 70%.

Comment: i have edited answer as well, what on commenting background color of `#nav` is that what you looking for ?

Comment: Your edit seems to be my problem.  The #nav is suppose to set the background color to 70% opacity, which it has.  But then the first LI element (a blank non navigation item) needs to be completely transparent, but it is adopting the 70% opacity.  Then the rest of the LI elements should go back to 70%, but they are completely solid right now.  The bar should go like this:  first li completely transparent, and then the rest 70%.  But it is showing up like this.  First li 70%, all the rest  completely solid, and then the last 70% again.  Hope that isn't too confusing.

Comment: It might help to go to my website.  I want the whole bar 70% transparent except for the far left (so my logo can be there), I want it fully solid. [link](www.tutorwithkatie.org)[/link]

Comment: i have added via gradient solution option. please check. that would make your nav half of full transparent and other half of your desired color. you can further look on those css property and manage to fit on yours.